# What's the easiest way to send 802.11 frames using C?

Tags: c, packet, wifi

I'm a beginner to C, I've recently decided to make migrate this project to C from using Scapy/Python, *solely* because I want better performance. I wish to send layer 2 data, specifically beacon frames to advertise an access point.

So far I have found that I need to (or rather could) use libpcap and a Linux header called ieee80211.h that pre-defines packets, that's all I could gather from the other questions. I've found other information which says I should use raw sockets instead of libpcap? I'm not sure if this is all I need. Most of the information and tutorials I have found on Google refer to packet sniffing, not sending.

How do I define a custom frame and/or packet (e.g. a beacon frame or association request) and then simply send it to wlan0 etc.?

Comment: You don't mention an OS, so I assume this is Linux?

Comment: He mentions "a Linux header".

Comment: I scanned the question a few times, and never saw Linux :-)

Comment: Yes this is for Linux. I assume libpcap and winpcap are very similar? I don't expect this to be multiplatform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I might update this. I used libpcap.

You just need to create a handle with your device, set it to monitor mode successfully (important), check the data link type (e.g. 802.11 with Radiotap for layer 2) then use `pcap_sendpacket(handle, packetArrayContainingHex, size);`. Hard part is forming legal packets that aren't rejected or dropped, taking a look in wireshark helps.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/) might help. It basically opens the driver at raw packet level and creates the whole packet to send over the wire, as your question suggests.

Comment: This has pointed me in what seems like the right direction, I need to look into raw socket programming/networking. Thanks! I currently need to figure out how to bind a socket to a certain interface.